Connecting bodies together in jbox2d
Im trying to connect bodies together to make some sort of a "building" system or more specifically im trying to make multiple "blocks" connect to eachother but Struggling to figure out what's the best method to do it I tried using joints (created a jointDef and a joint) but I have no idea how. I can make a single large body but I want different parts of the body to have different friction values

Can you edit to include an example of what you're specifically trying to implement? Just saying that it's a "building" system is vague - what are you trying to build?

Thanks for pointing it out i edited it

It would help if you describe what it is you're building, or what criteria it should fulfill. Building a dwelling in the Sims, a bridge or tower in World of Goo, a rollercoaster in a Tycoon game, a siege weapon in Besiege, and a spaceship in Kerbal Space Program will all have different considerations. When you say you "tried using joints", what code did you write specifically, and where did you get stuck, or get a resulting behaviour that differed from what you wanted?

Well im not making something specific the whole point of what im making is for people to have the creative freedom to make whatever they like

In Box2D friction is set on Fixtures not the Body, so if you simply want a Body with parts that have different friction you can construct a Body with many Fixtures.
